# get list of spring integration inbound adapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am planning to use control bus feature in spring integration for managing inbound endpoints i.e. inbound file adapter,message driven adapter etc.

In order for control bus to work , adapter id is mandatory. I don't want to hard code the id. Is there a way to list all inbound adapters and get Id ?

Comment: how to use `org.springframework.integration.annotation.Role` in Spring Integration DSL.

I tried using @Role annotation on IntegrationFlow bean, however when i queried for `roleController.getRoles()` and empty list was returned.

@Role works with @ServiceActiviator and other Spring Integration java configuration but how to use it with Spring Integration DSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inbound Channel Adapters are represented by the `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`. All message driven channel Adapters are `MessageProducerSupport` or `MessageGatewaySupport`.

You need to request `BeanFactory.getBeansForType()` for all those mentioned classes.

At the same time consider to use their common `Lifecycle` interface if you are going to deal only with their `start()/stop()` functions.

There is also `RoleController` to manage groups of lifecycles: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#endpoint-roles

Comment: Thanks Artem. I will give it a try.